# Need to check ForeignKey references a specific object before saving

Tags: python, django, validation, model

I am new to Django (and Python in general) and have a Model validation question.

I have 2 models, team and game. 2 teams play in a game, and the winner field can be blank/null:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Game(models.Model):
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='away_games')
    away_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='home_games')
    home_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(21)])
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)

    def check_winner_played(self):
        if not (winner and (winner.id == away_team.id or winner.id == home_team.id)):
            # raise error("Winner did not compete")
```

I need to ensure that the winner is either the `away_team` or the `home_team`, not just any team. I created the `check_winner_played` method, but I have no idea how to call that on `.save()`. This will only be in the admin section, so I dont think I should be using Form validation. In my mind, it seems like the validation should be done at the Model level.

Also, if there are any things in here that make you stop and say 'this guy has no idea what he is doing.' let me know. Looking for any pointers I can get. Specifically, am I validating the `week IntegerField` max value correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to choose another way in determining the winner of the team,
since you have more than one state but winning the game. It could also be an equal score.

The information who won the game is actually indirectly determined by the score of the teams, so try to model the winning game with a property that uses the score to return the winner.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='away_games')
    away_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='home_games')
    home_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(21)])

    @property
    def winner():
        if self.away_score > self.home_score:
            return self.away_team
        elif self.away_score < self.home_score:
            return self.home_team
        else:
            return None
```

This will eliminate your need for additional validation. If you really want to use validators you should read the django docs about validators first: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should raise an error - if winner is not blank and its not either the away_team or home_team.
Notice its overriding the save method so this validation will be done on Game.save()

```
class Team(models.Model):
        abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
        location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Game(models.Model):
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='away_games')
    away_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='home_games')
    home_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(21)])
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not (self.winner and (self.winner == self.away_team or self.winner == self.home_team)):
              raise ValidationError('Winner Error')
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Since you're rasing a ValidationError you will need to import ValidationError in your models.py (at the top):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
```

Comment: so this solution works, django throws a validation error with the code 'winner error'. but when I try to submit what would be a valid winner thru the admin site I get a name error for Post is not defined. I tried `from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse`in `models.py` but the error NameError is still being thrown. What do I need to import and where?

Comment: It's in your code. 

Replace: `super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` with `super(Game, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: awesome that works thank you.

Now it allows one of the playing teams to be submitted as the winner. If I submit a team that did not play, then I get the Winner Error thrown. Now is there a docs section on how to throw that error as a bad entry on the form (just flash a red error message) rather than showing the Django error page with a stack trace?

Comment: Try returning a simple boolean expression instead of raising a validation error. So, instead of `raise ValidationError('Winner Error')` you can write `return False` and after the `super(Game, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` line add `return True`. This way when use Game.save() it should return a boolean variable - you can do something like `if Game.save():`